# Reopen "How can I increase the chances of scoring an interview when meeting a company a career fair"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[How can I increase the chances of scoring an interview when meeting a company at a career fair?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96881/how-can-i-increase-the-chances-of-scoring-an-interview-when-meeting-a-company-at#comment294189_96881) was marked as a duplicate of [What should you do to get the most out of a career fair?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9096/what-should-you-do-to-get-the-most-out-of-a-career-fair)

As I said in a comment on the question:
"I don't think just being about career fair strategies makes this a duplicate. This question is about someone who already understands the benefits of a career fair wanting to connect and move forward with a specific company, the other is someone trying to figure out the point of attending the career fair and how to benefit from the whole thing in general. Some of the answers on the other question may help this poster **partially**, but won't address the meat of the question. I would like to see a good answer to this question as well, it's a common situation and will be helpful to lots of users."

It would be nice to see this question reopened so that the OP's specific question can be answered.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify your main question. I agree that this is a distinct and more specific case. Both your current question and the general question (i.e. without the context of you having already applied) would be distinct enough to be worth covering in my view. I support the reopen. Ping me after it gets a few more reopen votes.